# Do I need a new thread to fill a custom ListAdapter?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Do I need to load my custom ListAdapter in another thread? I have done so previously, but I also downloaded the data in that same thread.

Are there any pros or cons to loading a ListAdapter with or without a thread? Is loading a thread that resource intensive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your list has anything more than a trivial amount of entries in it or you're getting anything off of the network or from disk, you should be loading them on a separate thread. But it's actually really easy to do this with the new [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) classes. They were basically made for this kind of stuff. They'll take care of doing all the loading stuff on a separate thread without you having to mess with all the nasty threading stuff. You just tell it what you want to load and it takes care of doing the stuff in the background for you.

Note that while the Loader classes weren't introduced until API-11, you can still access them from API-5 and up using the android [Support Package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

It sounds like for your case in particular, you should use an [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html).

Comment: I'm developing for Android 2.2 as a baseline requirement. (Just read the second half of your post, I see) My question, however, is whether it is NEEDED to use a new thread for loading an adapter.

Comment: Just edited my answer to address this when you actually need the loader.

Comment: Yep, that was the general conclusion that I came to, but I wanted to check if it was in line with what others agreed upon. I'm going to wait to mark this for anything, just to get more input from others if it is available. +1 for now.